# How do I change listview item size programmatically of winjs listview?

Tags: windows-8, winjs

I have template binded with the listview in windows store application which I am developing using html5 and javascript. I have a requirement to change the size of the listview item programmatically. Basically I have a input type range on my page. User will change the value of the input and according to that value I should be able to change the size of the listview item programmatically.

Any help or pointer will be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but I have just spent hours doing extensive tests (because I didn't feel like switching to grid mode) and I found a very simple way that would allow you to have items of any height without them overlapping,I though I would share it, all you need to do is add this to your css:

```
.win-listview .win-listlayout .win-container { 
    height:auto; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the size of the items in a listview using the class set on the item in the template. You can:

1. Define different classes for the different sizes you want
2. Define the sizes in CSS. Example:

   ```
   .small {
       height: 150px;
       width: 150px;
   }

   .large {
       height: 300px;
       width: 300px;
   }
   ```
3. Set the appropriate class on the template item:

   ```
   var templateItem = document.querySelector("#regularListIconTextTemplate .regularListIconTextItem");
   WinJS.Utilities.addClass(templateItem, "large");
   ```
4. Refresh the listview:

   ```
   element.querySelector("#listView").winControl.forceLayout();
   ```

Comment: Thanks Tarek, I have tried that option and it works fine for predefined size like from 150px to 300 px etc. I am looking for smooth increase say.. 101,102,103px in the size of the tile and that too without refreshing the whole list. 

The user should be able to control the size of each tile by sliding the finger on the input range control. The list should not be refreshed ( forceLayout refreshes the list).